# to find the address of the beginning and of the end of a route

Tags: android, location, geocoding

I'm receving GPS data via DDMS using a KML file in android and I'm using the following code:

```
public class screen4 extends MapActivity 

{    


List<GeoPoint> geoPointsArray = new ArrayList<GeoPoint>();

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.screen4); 

        lm = (LocationManager)getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);    

        locationListener = new MyLocationListener();


        mapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.mapview1);

        mapView.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);

        mc = mapView.getController();

       lm.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,0,0,locationListener);

   }


private class MyLocationListener implements LocationListener

    {

        @Override
        public void onLocationChanged(Location loc) {

            if (loc != null) {                         

                latitude=(int)(loc.getLatitude()* 1E6);

                longitude=(int)(loc.getLongitude()* 1E6);


           GeoPoint p = new GeoPoint(latitude,longitude);
        geoPointsArray.add(p);

      mc.animateTo(p);

              mc.setZoom(17);     

                mapView.invalidate();

                mapView.setSatellite(true);
           }

        }
```

In onLocationChanged() I retrieve the GPS data and store it in GeoPoint p, what I want to do is to find out the address of the first point(latitude,longitude) and of the last point whose GPS data I retrieve.

My question is: Does my program stay blocked at this line:

```
lm.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,0,0,locationListener);
```

until all the GPS data is retrieved?

In this way I can apply Geocoder for the geoPointsArray(0) and after that for geoPointsArray(maxSize).

My problem is that I don't know how this program  works,so I can't really figure out when all my GPS data is retrieved(my geoPointsArray is full) and so where to apply Geocoder.

**Question2:**

In the moment I start to receive location updates I want to connect to a remote server and send all the GPS data that is stored in geoPointArray to the server. Any idea of where should I start my thread? I have a bunch of code lines but I guess no one is going to read that!

Comment: @adrian I pulled your "question 2" from your edit to CommonsWare's answer and edited it into your original question. Generally though, if you have a follow-up question, you should ask another question.

Comment: @meagar And when I started to think that he is going to answer..=)))...I really don't know how this site works...is there someone who follows all the questions that are posted here?

Comment: Now,no one is going to answer to my question:(((

Comment: @adrian There are many people who watch the site and answer questions. Please read the [faq](http://stackoverflow.com/faq). As I said, you'd be better off asking another question since you've already accepted an answer to this one, effectively marking it "closed" or "solved". Stack Overflow is not a chat room; you don't get interactive one-on-one help here. You post your question and members of the community post answers.

Comment: Have the member of the community thought that a chat room on android would be more efficient:)))....Thx man:)

Comment: @adrian There are chat rooms out there, this is not one of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My question is:does my program stays blocked at this line:
>   lm.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,0,0,locationListener);
>   until all the GPS data is retrieved????

No. Location updates are asynchronous.